# How to limit SQL query which uses join with Many-to-Many relationships?

Tags: sql, join, limit, offset

I have one table (Award) that is linked to another (Person) through intermediate table (AwardPerson). I want to select Awards with associated Persons in one query.
Basically my query looks something like this:

```
      SELECT Award.title
             Person.name
        FROM Award
  OUTER JOIN AwardPerson ON Award.id = AwardPerson.award_id
        JOIN Person ON AwardPerson.person_id = Person.id
```

Now I want to add pagination, allowing user to specify limit and offset.
If I just add

```
       LIMIT 5 OFFSET 25
```

I will get less Award rows if I have more than one person associated with one Award. Here's result example:

```
"Fastest pizza eater" "Bob"
"Fastest pizza eater" "Alice"
"Fastest pizza eater" "Mary"
"Biggest stomach"     "John"
"Best manners"        "Sam"
```

First award is repeated three times, because there are 3 AwardPerson records for one Award record. That's why for query with LIMIT 5 I got only 3 Award entities.
But what I wanted is 5 Awards with no matter how much Persons attached.

Is there any way I can LIMIT and OFFSET query, that has joins with Many-to-Many relationships?

The only solution, I can think of is to always select more than asked (like LIMIT * 3) and then drop extra results. But this approach does not work good with OFFSETs (imagine how do I tweak OFFSET 1000).

Also, there is implicit requirement for this query to work fast :-)

**UPDATE**

The solution I found in [Is it possible to LIMIT results from a JOIN query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466273/135079) is to make subquery which adds new column with some CASE-WHEN-ELSE logic. This approach is too hard to implement using sqlalchemy, so I am thinking about removing offset feature from my application...

**UPDATE 2**

There is another solution. Making two database queries. First SELECT DISTINCT award.id with applied LIMIT, and then fetch whole request using IN condition.

Comment: Why you join it with person if you need awards? What will happen with persons?

Comment: I need both awards and persons. I post-process results in following manner. I go through rows and check if award is the same as previous. If so, I append current person to existing award. Otherwise I create new Award with attached Person.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Updated question with "5 Awards with no matter how much Persons attached."

Comment: If it is mysql you can do group by award.id, mysql will take one person record. May be some others will work too, not oracle, not postgres.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I use MS SQL and sqlite. And I join 4 more tables, so grouping does not work in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL limit SELECT but not JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296244/sql-limit-select-but-not-join)
and [Is it possible to LIMIT results from a JOIN query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465878/is-it-possible-to-limit-results-from-a-join-query?rq=1)